# Correlation between Two Factor Gaussian Shortrate Model and Black Scholes Model

Tags: black-scholes, correlation, short-rate

I want to implement a two factor Gaussian Shortrate Model
\begin{align}
r(t) & = x(t) + y(t) + \phi(t), \\
dx(t) & = -ax(t)dt + \sigma dB_1 (t), \\
dy(t) & = -by(t)dt + \eta dB_2(t),
\end{align}
with correlation $dB_2(t)dB_2(t) = \rho_{12}dt$ and do have the price process of an asset $S(t)$ given bei the Black Scholes equation
\begin{align}
dS(t) = S(t) \big[(r(t)-y)dt + \mu (t) dB_S (t) \big], \qquad y>0, \,\ S(0)=0,
\end{align}
so that you have
\begin{align}
S(t) = e^{\int_0^t (r(s)-y)ds - 0.5 \cdot \int_0^t \mu (s)^2 ds + \int_0^t \mu(s) dB_S(s)} .
\end{align}

Thanks for your help!

My Question is: 
How do i have to choose the correlations 
\begin{align}
dB_1(t)dB_S(t) &= \rho_{1S} dt, \\
dB_2(t) dB_S(t) &= \rho_{2S} dt,
\end{align}
so that i can get a predetermined correlation between $dB_S(t)$ and the sum $d(B_1(t) +B_2(t))$, i.e. i want to habe
\begin{align}
d(B_1(t) +B_2(t))dS(t) = \rho dt
\end{align}.

Comment: For simplicity, you can assume that $\rho_{2S}=0$.